# Split to fit packets c# UDP

Tags: c#, split, size, package

How can i split a packet into smaller parts, and then send it?
Currently i have tried doing it very manually, for example an image.

I would have 2 udp clients, have an image that´s, let´s say 800x600.
Send 1 udp client with 800x300 and the other 800x300.

Then merge them.

But i am thinking there must be a better way, some kind of function to to this?
As it becomes extremely hard with big packages, i will have to make like 10+ udpclients.

```
    private void Initialize()
    { 


        Bitmap holder = new Bitmap(640, 480);

        pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1200);
        EndPoint ourEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        EndPoint remoteEP = (EndPoint)(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1700));
        EndPoint remoteEP2 = (EndPoint)(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1701));


        udpcap = new UdpClient();
        udpcap1 = new UdpClient();
        udpcap.Client.Bind(remoteEP);
        udpcap1.Client.Bind(remoteEP2);

     }


 private void Listen()
    {
        while (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            byte[] data = udpcap.Receive(ref adress);
            byte[] data2 = udpcap1.Receive(ref adress);
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(byteArrayToImage(data).Width + byteArrayToImage(data2).Width, Math.Max(byteArrayToImage(data).Height, byteArrayToImage(data2).Height));
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.DrawImage(byteArrayToImage(data), 0, 0);
                g.DrawImage(byteArrayToImage(data2), byteArrayToImage(data).Width, 0);
            }

            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = bitmap;

        }
    }
    private static Image cropImage(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
    {
        Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
        Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
        return (Image)(bmpCrop);
    }
    private void Send()
    {
        bool p = true;
        while (capcon == true)
        {
            Rectangle h = new Rectangle(0, 0, 320, 480);
            Bitmap holder = new Bitmap(640, 480);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(holder);
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(1920, 1200), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            byte[] u = imageToByteArray(cropImage(holder, h));
            udpcap.Send(u, u.Length, adress.Address.ToString(), 1700);
            h = new Rectangle(320, 0, 320, 480);
            byte[] u1 = imageToByteArray(cropImage(holder, h));
            udpcap1.Send(u1, u1.Length, adress.Address.ToString(), 1701);

        }
    }
```

Here is the code, what it´s doing is simple.
Take a screenshot of the desktop.
place it in 640x480 bitmap (much less then the desktop size though).

Send 2 packages with 2 halves of the picture.

Recieve the data, combine them, and place them as a background.

Now, this works for 640x480, which is very small.

Now if i want to do it with something higher, i must make extremely many packages.
So i wonder if it is possible to have it a bit more, automatic.

Why i am splitting packages and using many clients is cause i don´t know how to send something bigger than the buffer (65kb), tried searching on it, but i don´t understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I think a better approach would be to use TCP instead of UDP.

UDP offer no guaranty that the other side will receive all of the packets and that they will be received in the same order as they were sent. I guess that is why you are using two different clients at the same time? Using this approach, you will have to manage packets by yourself (split them, reassemble them, make sure you receive all of them, etc.)

TCP is better for large transfers. It will give you out of the box sequencing, fragmentation, flow control, etc. There is a little more overhead, but I guess it will make no difference in your case.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=VS.71).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: If you need to support multiple clients at the same time, take a look at this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d9e4bcbc-3149-4817-8d7c-37cdb29f8be0/tcp-server-with-multiple-clients

Comment: I wanted to test TCP, but i don´t understand how it works, UDP is so much easier (noob as programming here).  And Latency is extremely important here. 
Andi want to know, when is it that udp packets will not arrive? 
is it only on the global internet (meaning it can disappear while jumping around on routers etc)?

Cause if so, then it doesn´t matter to me, as i am using it for a unique situation, you can compare it to LAN.

Why i am using many clients is cause i don´t know how to send stuff bigger than the allowed buffer (65kb).

Comment: Well I placed a few urls to interesting examples that should help you understand how it works. As for the lost packet, it could also happen on a LAN if there is too much packet to handle at a particular moment in time, or if there is a glitch on the network, etc.

Comment: And for the latency thing, I'm probably sure the overhead of waiting for all packets to be ready and reassembling them will be way more important than what TCP would cause...

Comment: I am trying to make a for loop for using udp by sending till it´s done, but well, not sure how to make it.

But what do you mean, is udp going to make higher latency than tcp?

Comment: On the network, no, but on the client side, probably, depending on how you handle the packets.

Comment: I pretty much solved this, got help with how to send and handle the packets. It seems to work well, though i am wondering if it is faster then using TCP, will have to try out later.